# toggling sibling buttons in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

http://jsfiddle.net/s89a4/3/ shows how I have placed yes/no/na buttons for each row of a table. I want to click on a value such that its siblings get toggled.

How can I achieve this? Tried out the sibling jquery methods but can't pull it through.

```
<div class="btn-group">
<button id="yesbutton" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Yes</button>
<button id="nobutton" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">No</button>
<button id="nabutton" type="button" class="btn btn-info">N/A</button>
</div>
```

I can toggle the individual buttons by clicking twice on each. However I need the siblings to be toggled for that particular row. (my fiddle does not show even the toggling somehow but I think it puts across the point) thanks.

Comment: Where's the yes/no/na buttons in the jsfiddle?

Comment: Check out the boostrap page: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups

Comment: None of your code here is in your fiddle.

Comment: I would suggest shortening the delay on your dropdown.  It is not the "expected behavior" and may be confusing or weird or make someone think something is wrong with your site.  When I first hovered the nav, nothing happened, so I clicked  and it seemed like my click is what opened it.

Comment: sorry about the wrong link folks - here's my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/s89a4/1/

Comment: corrections on the button IDs -> http://jsfiddle.net/s89a4/2/ As I said, the individual buttons are toggling on clicking them, but I need only one button in a row to be "active" at any time since this is a yes/no/na scenario.

Comment: please ignore the earlier fiddles - this one is the perfect example for my problem -> http://jsfiddle.net/s89a4/3/

Comment: This the sort of thing you're after? http://jsfiddle.net/Brv5A/

Comment: you nailed it @patrick - it now sounds too obvious :) http://jsfiddle.net/Brv5A/1/ <-- modified to my needs

Comment: Good to hear : ) posted it as an answer for closure's sake, if you wouldn't mind accepting it.

Comment: @Patrick thanks again! should have done this long ago - marked your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by toggling the needed class on your element, while removing the unwanted class(es) from its siblings. Simple example would be:

```
$('#translateTable').on( 'click', '#yesbutton', function (event) {

    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");

});
```

[Demo for you.](http://jsfiddle.net/Brv5A/)